# Selecting element w/o selector in js

Tags: javascript, html

I knew in js I can select this -> `<div id='x'>xd</div>` element via `document.getElementById('x')` or `document.querySelector('#x')`, but today I discovered I can just select it writing `x` like it's a variable in my script already. The question is what is this method called and what is browser support?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hah TIL: it turns out it is part of the [HTML specifications](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object)

I would recommend to avoid using that feature, that could cause a lot of confusion and waste of time on *a bug that is actually a feature*.

Say you have declared x and given it a value, it makes it virtually impossible to retrieve the element with id `x` and use your own separate variable `x` with more likely a different meaning.